# Calling a specific respond_to block method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to format a `link_to` tag in order to generate a pdf file (wicked_pdf gem) with the following respond_to block:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "file_name" 
      end
    end
```

I have already created blocks with javascript method. But it was then fairly easy to get the JS rendered : only add `remote: true` to my form.

In case of other mime types or respond_to block methods, I have no clue how to write my `link_to` tag to let the controller know I want a specific method against another...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways that the `respond_to` block determines which format to render is by looking at the extension of the url. For instance, if I have in my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index', as: 'home'
end
```

and then in my controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render inline: 'HTML' }
      format.pdf { render inline: 'PDF' }
    end
  end
end
```

I can get the `format.pdf` by using a `.pdf` extension:

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000/home/index.pdf
# PDF
$ curl http://localhost:3000/home/index.html
# HTML
```

When creating a `link_to`, you can tell it which extension to use by passing it into the `url_for` (or whichever named route helper you're using):

```
<%= link_to 'View the PDF', url_for(controller: 'home', action: 'index', format: 'pdf') %>
# => <a href="/home/index.pdf">View the PDF</a>
<%= link_to 'View the PDF', home_path(format: 'pdf') %>
# => <a href="/home/index.pdf">View the PDF</a>
```

The way I believe `remote: true` works is by setting the **Accept** header. which Rails also uses to figure out what `respond_to` item to call:

```
$ curl -H 'Accept: application/pdf' http://localhost:3000/home/index
# PDF
```